# Should I use ndb structured property or a seperate model to limit my GAE queries. Basis data modeling questions.

Tags: python, google-app-engine, database-design, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to reformat a previous question I posed in a more meaningful way here. If I'm not asking the correct question, or not providing enough information please let me know.

I have data coming in from a Pi that is in the below format and I would like a meaningful way of representing the data in the datastore (ndb)to limit my writes when it arrives, and limit the number of queries I need to make to find the correct place to put the data (aka Zone):

**Data comes like this:**

> {'rssi': '*', 'source_addr': '**87:ea:66:be:19:d9**',
>   'id':'rx_io_data', 'samples': [{'adc-0': 253, 'adc-1': 2}, {'**adc-0':
>   252,'adc-1': 2**}, {'adc-0': 252, 'adc-1': 2}, {'adc-0': 253, 'adc-1':
>   1}, {'adc-0': 252, 'adc-1': 2}], 'options': '\x00'}

I've highlighted the information that is important (I don't need code for putting data in. more an appropriate structure for my models)..

So I will use the MAC address to find the "Zone" the readings should be associated with, then I will need to use Zone to lookup associated sensors (seems convoluted),then map the sensor (adc-0, adc-1) to it's human readable mapping( temperature, or heart monitor). I want to keep the total readings, and the individual sensor readings such that later I can query for all heart monitor sensors in all zones, or per zone...

**So far I have this which seems convoluted and requires a lot of querying and puts:**

```
class Sensors(ndb.Model): # parent Zone
    sensorname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True) # Heart, Temp
    sensorpin = ndb.StringProperty(required=True) # adc-0, or adc-1 ... 

class Zone(ndb.Model):
    zname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True) # Name of zone like "Room# or Patient#"
    zonemac  = ndb.StringProperty(required=True) # MAC of network adapter
    homekey = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Home, required=True)
    datecreated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Readings(ndb.Model): # parent Zone
    datecreated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    alldata = ndb.JsonProperty(required=True) # store all the readings in json for later debug

class Reading(ndb.Model): # parent is Sensor or zone ? individual sensor readings ?
    readingskey =  ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Readings, required=True) # full reading
    value = ndb.IntegerProperty(required= True ) # or 0
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required = True) # Heart sensor, temp sensor,... )
```

**Potential Option:**

```
class Sensors(ndb.Model):
    sensorname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True) # Heart, Temp
    sensorpin = ndb.StringProperty(required=True) # adc-0, or adc-1 ... 

class Zone(ndb.Model):
    zname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True) # Name of zone like "Room# or Patient#"
    zonemac  = ndb.StringProperty(required=True) # MAC of network adapter
    homekey = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Home, required=True)
    sensors = ndb.StructuredProperty(Sensors, repeated = True) #sensors you can get sensor name but how do you map to adc-0 or whatever
    datecreated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Readings(ndb.Model): # parent Zone
    datecreated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    alldata = ndb.JsonProperty(required=True) # store all the readings in json for later debug
    individualreading = ndb.StructuredProperty(Reading, repeat=True)

class Reading(ndb.Model): # parent is Sensor or zone ? individual sensor readings ?
    readingskey =  ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Readings, required=True) # full reading
    value = ndb.IntegerProperty(required= True ) # or 0
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required = True) # Heart sensor, temp sensor,... )
```

The trick is all I get from the devices are MAC and sensor mappings (ADC-0, ADC-1 and values)

So I need to look for the zones they belong to, and the sensors they map to to later search for them..

I have done very little database modeling so I have no clue how to do the modeling for this. I could create new models and reference them with key properties or created structuredproperties and query for those (eliminating the Sensors model) but then still having to do Readings and Reading after the lokups.

Any help is much appreciated.

And yes I've read the [ndb properties](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#options) and [Filtering queries by structured properties](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filtering_structured_properties) and a few similar SO posts like this [one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445639/ndb-query-for-repeated-structured-property-by-ancestor)

Answer (score 2):

I guess using a StructuredProperty would save a small amount of write operations. What I would propose though is figuring out which properties don't have to be indexed and declaring them with option indexed=False. As stated on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#options), " Unindexed properties cost fewer write ops than indexed properties.", and by experience I can tell you that you can really save a lot of write ops this way.

Comment: Thanks, Is my thinking of how to create these models correct. Is this an acceptable database design for the spec's laid out or am I drastically overcomplicating this.

Comment: You are overcomplicating things a bit. Your thinking seems more appropriate for a relational SQL DB. In a NoSQL datastore like App Engine's Datastore, it makes more sense to have the data "flattened down" instead of using complex relationships, even if the data gets copied to multiple tables. For example the Reading table could also hold the Zone and Sensor key making the path to find the required data shorter and saving you a few reads. And since you will be using the key to retrieve the data, the ndb's internal memcache will, in most cases, return the data without querying the datastore.